# Sum over an increasing number of columns of a data frame in R

Tags: r

I need to extract summed subsets of a data.frame row-by-row and use the output to return a new data.frame. However, I want to increase the number of columns to sum across by 4 each time. So, for example, I want to extract the 1st column by itself, then the sum of columns 2 to 6 on a row-by-row basis, then columns 7 to 15 and so on.

I have this code that returns the sum of a constant number of columns across a data.frame (by a maximum number of trials) into a new data.frame- I just need to find a way to add the escalating function.

```
t<- max(as.numeric(df[,c(5)]))

process.row <- function (x){
  sapply(1:t,function(i){
return(sum(as.numeric(x[c((6+(i-1)*5):(10+(i-1)*5))] 
)
)
)
 })
}

t(apply(df,1,process.row)) -> collated.data
```

I've been really struggling with a way to do this so thanks very much for any help. I couldn't find an answer to this elsewhere so apologies if I've missed something.

Comment: There are typo in your `process.row` function.

Comment: Thanks- corrected I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was thinking you wanted to sum the rows of the selected subset of columns.  If so, perhaps this will help.

```
# fake data
mydf <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(45*5), nrow=5))
mydf

# prepare matrix of start and ending columns
n <- 20
i <- 1:n
ncols <- 1 + (i-1)*4
endcols <- cumsum(ncols)
startcols <- c(1, cumsum(ncols[-length(endcols)])+1)
mymat <- cbind(endcols, startcols)

# function to sum the rows
myfun <- function(df, m) {
  # select subset with end columns within the dimensions of the given df
  subm <- m[m[, 2] <= dim(df)[2], ]
  # sum up the selected columns of df by rows
  sapply(1:dim(subm)[1], function(j) 
    rowSums(df[, subm[j, 1]:subm[j, 2], drop=FALSE]))
}

mydf
myfun(df=mydf, m=mymat)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a function that gives `x` (the lower value of the series), which looks like this for the sequence-part `i`:

[image: Function]

In `r`, the code looks like this:

```
# the foo part of the function
foo <- function(x) ifelse(x > 0, 1 + (x - 1) * 4, 0)

# the wrapper of the function 
min.val <- function(i){
  ifelse(i == 1, 1, 1 + sum(sapply(1:(i - 1), foo)))
}

# takes only one value
min.val(1)
# [1] 1
min.val(2)
# [1] 2
min.val(3)
# [1] 7

# to calculate multiple values, use it like this
sapply(1:5, min.val)
#[1]  1  2  7 16 29
```

If you want to get the maximum number, you can create another function, which looks like this

```
max.val <- function(i) min.val(i + 1) - 1
sapply(1:5, max.val)
#[1]  1  6 15 28 45
```

### Testing:

```
# creating a series to test it
series <- 1:20
min.vals <- sapply(series, min.val)
max.vals <- sapply(series, max.val)

dat <- data.frame(min = min.vals, max = max.vals)
# dat
#    min max
# 1    1   1
# 2    2   6
# 3    7  15
# 4   16  28
# 5   29  45
# 6   46  66
# 7   67  91
# 8   92 120
# 9  121 153
# 10 154 190
# 11 191 231
# 12 232 276
# 13 277 325
# 14 326 378
# 15 379 435
# 16 436 496
# 17 497 561
# 18 562 630
# 19 631 703
# 20 704 780
```

Does that give you what you want?

Comment: I think this gives the number of the columns but I still wasn't sure how to sum them? The above answer has worked well for me though. Thanks for your help!